# Create and write to file on MIPS

Tags: file, mips

I'm trying to create a file named "exit.txt", and write some data on it. I have tried different flags and modes, but that doesn't seem to work. This is the code I'm using:

```
str_exit: .asciiz "/home/LinuxPc/Desktop/exit.txt"

file_write:

li $v0, 13
la $a0, str_exit
li $a1, 1
la $a2, 0
syscall
```

Is there any way to make it work ??
Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer of gusbro (open file stream before writing) it might help to set the flags and mode for the open file call as follows:

```
li $a1, 0x41            
li $a2, 0x1FF
```

This sets the flag to the hex value 0x41 which tells the call to first create the file. While the mode is set to hex value 0x1FF which is converted to the binary value
0000 0000 0001 1111 1111 that sets the file permission for:
(...)0 111(n) 111(g) 111(others).

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You put the code to open a file in write mode, but you didn't write anything into the file.
Here goes an example of how to open/write/close a file:

```
.data
str_exit: .asciiz "test.txt"
str_data: .asciiz "This is a test!"
str_data_end:

.text

file_open:
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, str_exit
    li $a1, 1
    li $a2, 0
    syscall  # File descriptor gets returned in $v0
file_write:
    move $a0, $v0  # Syscall 15 requieres file descriptor in $a0
    li $v0, 15
    la $a1, str_data
    la $a2, str_data_end
    la $a3, str_data
    subu $a2, $a2, $a3  # computes the length of the string, this is really a constant
    syscall
file_close:
    li $v0, 16  # $a0 already has the file descriptor
    syscall
```